# Is it possible to import the NgModule objects from a separate file?

Tags: angular

I am trying to clean up the structure of my app and put everything into logical files. I do this often in C#. Is it possible to pull the declarations out into a separate file and assign the value to the declarations variable on NgModule?

Before:

app.module.ts

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DirectNextStepComponent,
    TermsOfServiceComponent,
    PrivacyStatementComponent,
    WorkQueuesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UnitedMatTableComponent,
    ProcessDirectNextStepComponent,
],
```

Desired after:

app.module.ts

```
//this does not compile 
declarations : [] = components,
//this also does not compile
declarations = components,
```

app.declarations.ts

```
export const components = [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DirectNextStepComponent,
    TermsOfServiceComponent,
    PrivacyStatementComponent,
    WorkQueuesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UnitedMatTableComponent,
    ProcessDirectNextStepComponent,
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually possible. You might want to import them first in the declarations file:

```
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HelloComponent } from "./hello.component";
import { OneComponent } from "./one/one.component";
import { TwoComponent } from "./two/two.component";
import { ThreeComponent } from "./three/three.component";
import { FourComponent } from "./four/four.component";

export const components = [
  AppComponent,
  HelloComponent,
  OneComponent,
  TwoComponent,
  ThreeComponent,
  FourComponent
];
```

And then use it like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { components } from './app.declarations';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ components ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/declarations-in-a-separate-file-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.declarations.ts)** for your ref.

**PS:** This is a pattern I haven't really seen being endorsed by anyone though. It would be more of an anti-pattern in some scenarios. The reason for that would be a case wherein you might have to use the same component name at multiple places(`declarations`, `bootstrap`, `entryComponents`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand, have you tried with

`[... components]` in ES6 ?

Alternatively in typescript, you can try with a static array in a separated class:

```
export class Config {
   public static readonly components = []
```

}

and so:

```
Config.components
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it a separate Angular module? Put

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DirectNextStepComponent,
    TermsOfServiceComponent,
    PrivacyStatementComponent,
    WorkQueuesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UnitedMatTableComponent,
    ProcessDirectNextStepComponent,
],
exports: [/* same stuff as above */]
```

and in your AppModule simply add the one module (one line) to imports.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is a common way to do this:

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'foo',
  component: FooComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'bar',
  component: BarComponent
 },
]

@NgModule({ /* ... */ })
export class AppRoutingModule {
 static components = [
   BarComponent,
   FooComponent,
 ];
}
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [AppRoutingModule.components],
 imports: [AppRoutingModule, /* ... */]
})
export class AppModule { }
```